# Trying to do a minor refactor using lambdas in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, anonymous-function, anonymous-methods

I am working on part of a program (concerning speech recognition and a remote control car), where the code `transmit(XXXXX); disableAutoMode();` is repeated many times. For curiosity's sake I would like to convert this into a lambda function similar to this `var f = p -> transmit(p); disableAutoMode();` (forgive the `var`; I don't know what the type of the expression would be) and then call it in a way similar to this: `f("s");`, `f("a");` and `f("f");` or something similar to `f.call("s");`, `f.call("a");` and `f.call("f");`.

What is the correct syntax to use a simple lambda function in Java similar to how I described above? (What should I put down as it's type instead of saying `var`?)

Here is the block of code, if you're curious:

```
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        Log.i("onresult",text);
        ToastMaster(text);

        switch (text) {
            case "forward":
            case "go forward":
                transmit("f");
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "go back":
            case "go backward":
            case "back":
            case "backward":
            case "reverse":
                transmit("b");
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "skid left":
            case "go left":
                transmit("l");
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "skid right":
            case "go right":
                transmit("r");
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "turn left":
                transmit("q");
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "turn right":
                transmit("e");
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "reverse left":
                transmit("z");
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "reverse right":
                transmit("x");
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "stop":
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "automatic":
                toggleAutoMode(null);
                break;
            case "enable automatic mode":
                enableAutoMode();
                break;
            case "disable automatic mode":
                disableAutoMode();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you want a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html).

```
Consumer<String> function = (x) -> { transmit(x); disableAutoMode(); };
function.accept("hello!");
```

However I'm not sure why you want to use a lambda expression here, you could just create a plain old method and call that.

If you are after a more meaningful refactor one option would be to switch to a map of `String`, `Action/Runnable`. While you would end up with more code, the goal of refactors is not to "*make it smaller*" but to make it more readable/maintainable. By splitting each action into its own small self-contained class each action can be tested in isolation with minimal set-up. Each action can be reused (as it is just a class). With a good naming strategy it would be obvious to readers what is going on without having to dig through a large switch statement.

Comment: The win from lambdas comes not locally, but by turning the `switch` into something more data driven -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605401/3553087

Comment: You have recommended this same as the second part of my post.

Answer (score 8):

A more ambitious refactoring would build on the "turn code into data" principle that lambdas are all about, turning your switch statement from code to data as well.  How about:

```
// One-time setup of the machine
Map<String, Consumer<String>> actions = new HashMap<>();
actions.put("go forward", x -> { transmit(x); disableAutoMode(); });
actions.put(...)
...

public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        Log.i("onresult",text);
        ToastMaster(text);

        Consumer<String> action = actions.get(text);
        if (action != null)
            action.accept(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, what do you think about `actions.getOrDefault(text, x -> {}).accept(text)`? Is it reasonable?

Comment: Sure, that's fine too.  The high order bit was, "turn this big bag of code into a bag of data".

Answer (score 2):

Calling the lambda would be more tedious than using a simple helper method:

```
private void m(String x) {
    transmit(x);
    disableAutoMode();
}
```

An (more verbose) alternative would be using lambdas:

```
Consumer<String> consumer = (x) -> {
    transmit(x);
    disableAutoMode();
};
```

and then calling it similar to

```
consumer.accept("f");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is indeed possible with a lambda expression, but the saving won’t be so big:

```
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        Log.i("onresult",text);
        ToastMaster(text);

        Consumer<String> transmitDisable=s->{ transmit(s); disableAutoMode(); };
        switch (text) {
            case "forward": case "go forward":
                transmitDisable.accept("f");
                break;
            case "go back":  case "go backward": case "back":
            case "backward": case "reverse":
                transmitDisable.accept("b");
                break;
            case "skid left": case "go left":
                transmitDisable.accept("l");
                break;
            case "skid right": case "go right":
                transmitDisable.accept("r");
                break;
            case "turn left":     transmitDisable.accept("q"); break;
            case "turn right":    transmitDisable.accept("e"); break;
            case "reverse left":  transmitDisable.accept("z"); break;
            case "reverse right": transmitDisable.accept("x"); break;
            case "stop": disableAutoMode(); break;
            case "automatic": toggleAutoMode(null); break;
            case "enable automatic mode": enableAutoMode(); break;
            case "disable automatic mode": disableAutoMode(); break;
        }
    }
}
```

But you can remove the code duplication without lambda expressions as well, if you consider the not-so-commonly-used code flow control constructs of Java:

```
@Override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
    if (hypothesis != null) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        Log.i("onresult",text);
        ToastMaster(text);

        transmitAndDisable: {
            final String toTransmit;
            switch (text) {
                case "forward":    case "go forward": toTransmit="f"; break;
                case "go back":    case "go backward": case "back":
                case "backward":   case "reverse":  toTransmit="b"; break;
                case "skid left":  case "go left":  toTransmit="l"; break;
                case "skid right": case "go right": toTransmit="r"; break;
                case "turn left":     toTransmit="q"; break;
                case "turn right":    toTransmit="e"; break;
                case "reverse left":  toTransmit="z"; break;
                case "reverse right": toTransmit="x"; break;

                case "stop": disableAutoMode(); break transmitAndDisable;
                case "automatic": toggleAutoMode(null); break transmitAndDisable;
                case "enable automatic mode": enableAutoMode(); break transmitAndDisable;
                case "disable automatic mode": disableAutoMode(); break transmitAndDisable;
                default: break transmitAndDisable;
            }
            transmit(toTransmit);
            disableAutoMode();
        }
    }
}
```

The structure might be not so easy to read, but note how declaring the `toTransmit` as `final` helps greatly. Because it’s `final`, it can’t be initialized with a fall-back value, which implies that each alternative getting to the shared `transmit(…); disableAutoMode();` code must have initialized the variable exactly once.

In other words,

- if you forget to specify the `transmitAndDisable` label at a `break` of a case that is not intended to call the shared code, the compiler will immediately yell because `toTransmit` has not been initialized.
- if you forget a break between one of the alternatives intended to invoke the shared code, the compiler will immediately reject the code because it’s assigning `toTransmit` twice
- if you mistakenly specify the `transmitAndDisable` label at a `break` of a case that is intended to call the shared code, good compilers will issue a warning about an unused assignment

Comment: Personally I'd not do the second option here. I think it significantly hurts readability and does not save much compared to a plain old method.

Comment: @mlk: a plain old method is a viable option in this case and it’s definitely the preferred option if you have multiple common cases instead of a single dominant case. Note that the common case here is actually a *map* from the `case` string to the string passed to `transmit`. Doing the mapping using an actual `Map` allows to treat all common cases equally right inside the `switch` rather than in separate code, be it in a method or surrounding block…

Comment: @mlk: by the way, as noted, the second option provides a guaranty that you can’t forget a `break` for one of the common cases, which delegating to a method does not offer.

Comment: Honestly, aside from the guarantees regarding the `final toTransmit` variable and the `switch` construct, there's no way for the second option to be better than almost anything... It's hardly readable, depends on a kind of recursive declaration of the `switch` statement and dangerously resembles 70s or 80s code...

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: well, I accept this opinion, but if you think this over *consequently*, you should apply this to `switch` statements in general as everything you may say against labelled blocks applies to `switch` as well. That’s an acceptable point of view, but since this question was about a `switch` statement in the first place and both, `switch` and labelled statements are part of the Java language, I think my answer is valid for this specific question.

Comment: @Holger I always use `if` and `else if` and `else`. :) Anyways, I agree in that this is valid java code for this specific question. However, I think that you won't find many supporters to fight this labels battle...

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new about Java syntax. I've never seen those "labelled blocks and breaks" before